# Python's heapq, any iterative pop() methods?

Tags: python, iteration, heap

This problem may be very specific to what I'm working on at the moment, and I think focusing on the specifics of the heap would be a lot easier and clearer to explain.

Basically, I'm trying: 
(The actual heap I'm using returns a tuple but I don't think it affects anything, so for clarity's sake)

```
             while heap[0] < value:
                    heapq.heappop(heap)
```

And not surprisingly, it doesn't work. I assume this is because the heap cannot be iterated over the same time it is being modified.

Is there any way for me to peek into the heap and check if it below a certain value (and continuously)? I have also tried `heapq.nsmallest` but this returns a list which I do not need for any purpose.

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

EDIT: The heap is initialised as a list.

EDIT2:

Relevant code. Basically I have a heap of active connection requests that are sorted according to end-time (how long they are running till). The `start` variable is the start time (in seconds) of a new connection, and depending on whether the active connections overlap with this new connection, the connection may be rejected.

```
        # NetScheme
        if self.__net_scheme == ns.NetScheme.CIRCUIT:

            # Peek into the heap if heap non-empty
            if active_requests:
                #if active_requests[0][0] < start:
                #    req = heapq.heappop(active_requests)
                while active_requests[0][0] < start:
                    req = heapq.heappop(active_requests)
                    # Release circuit locks
                    for edge in req[1].getPath():
                        edge.isBusy = False
                        self.__graph.getCompEdge(edge).isBusy = False
```

This is ideally what I would like to run however I encounter the error which I suspect may not be related how I'm handling the heap.

```
while active_requests[0][0] < start:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The 2 lines commented underneath the first if statement is what I am currently using, however it limits the number of connections that could possibly be checked to only 1.

A case that I can think of is when there are 2 `active_requests` with end-times less than the start time of a new connection, my code will not be able to handle this.

Comment: what's your `heap` type, a list? Add more context code

Comment: That loop looks fine to me. You're not actually iterating over the heap, so you don't lose your place when you modify it. If you're having bugs, show us a [mcve].

Comment: Also, give more detail than "it doesn't work". We need to know what happens and what you expected to happen differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop doesn't work if the heap is empty or becomes empty before finding a value greater than your threshold. You should check for that situation before you index the heap to peek at the first item:

```
while heap and heap[0] < value:
```

Now, in your real code, you actually have an `if` that checks for an empty heap, but it doesn't help if the heap *becomes* empty while the loop is running (because you've popped the last value).

Try changing:

```
if active_requests:
    while active_requests[0][0] < start:
```

To:

```
while active_requests and active_requests[0][0] < start:
```